# Получить данные переменной с txt файла(с типами данных) в python

Tags: python, типы-данных, txt

Есть файл txt, который содержит текст следующего вида:

```
{content:[1, 0, {a:1, b:9, c:2}, g, 10], data{name:ivan, surname: ivanov}}
```

В общем файл содержит большой словарь, который в свою очередь может содержать списки, которые в свою очередь могут содержать словари и т.д. Копируя как текст и вставляя в качестве переменной получаю сильно тормозящую работу. Можно ли как ни будь импортировать данные переменной "а" из файла txt(с сохранением типов данных)?

Comment: А как `json` не пробовали из файла грузить?

Comment: Попробовал и получилось). Спасибо)